# How to view a single entry with oModel.read in UI5 Application

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to display a single entry with oModel.read in my UI5 application and store it in a variable.

What i want to do is, to select a single entry of my Model and store it in a variable:
If i execute my code i get the following in the Browser-Console:
https://ibb.co/FmPNSPm

Here is my code (but is not working):

```
var hostPort = "";

var oDataPath = "/.../KOMMI_SERVICE/";
var sServiceUrl= hostPort + oDataPath;
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel (sServiceUrl, true);
var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var text123;

oModel.read("/Komm(ZSMATERIALTEXT ='"+text123+")",oEntry,null,false,
              function(oData, oResponse){

             },function(err){
                console.log("err");
});
```

I think that this path `"/Komm(ZSMATERIALTEXT ='"+text123+")"` is not correct.

Comment: the result in console is a console.log of your oData? in your sample i only see a console.log for the error :)

Comment: no, i get this when i press the "network"-tab in the developer view in chrome and select the service entry

Comment: okey, your ODataPath variable, those `...` in `"/.../KOMMI_SERVICE/"` is to hide the real path you are using I hope

Comment: correct. The path to the service is working. If i am doing a oModel.create()... it is also working, but i want to extract a single entry with oModel.read() and i guess the access with my path is wrong

Comment: could you try: `var sKey = oModel.createKey("Komm", {ZSMATERIALTEXT :"text123"})` and then `oModel.read(sKey, { success: function(oData) {}, error: function(){}})`

Comment: is also not working. I get the following error: "invalid key predicate"

Comment: ye I was already doubting that ZSMATERIALTEXT would be your key, but based on what you've tried it looked like it was. Short Coding Sheep provided something you should be able to try :)

Comment: Why are you using `Model.read`? The SAPUI5 framework has great binding qualities from the view to a data source that don't require any code. `Model.read` always seems wrong to me...

Comment: is binding without Model.read more simple to store a single entry from Backend to a variable?

Comment: It depends on how you are using the variable? It seems you are reading some OData entity set, how does this value change any processing, UI display you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using filter. For example:

```
var sPath = "/Komm";
var oFilter = [
    new Filter("ZSMATERIALTEXT", "EQ", text123)
];

oModel.read(sPath, {
    filters: oFilter,
    success: function (oData, oResponse) {
        // save variable
    },
    error: function (oError) {
        // show error
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. how is the filter working? in text123 i want to store the value of ZSMATERIALTEXT.

Comment: @Eimerman Import sap.ui.model.Filter at the beginning. For example: sap.ui.define([ 'sap/ui/model/Filter' ], function (Filter) { ... }

Comment: your code above: "ZSMATERIALTEXT", "EQ", text123 -> does it select the ZSMATERIALTEXT which is the value of text123?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I think you're missing a " ' "...

```
oModel.read("/Komm(ZSMATERIALTEXT ='"+text123+"')",oEntry,null,false,
              function(oData, oResponse){

             },function(err){
                console.log("err");
});
```

Or

```
oModel.read("/Komm", {
            filters: [ 
              new sap.ui.model.Filter("ZSMATERIALTEXT", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, text123)
            ],
            success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                // do some...
            },
            error: function (oError) {
                // error
            }
        });
```

Comment: mm can you try this other example:
oModel.read("/Komm?$filter=ZSMATERIALTEXT eq '"+ text123 + "'",null, [], true, function ...

Comment: when i am using filter, do i have to define a entityset in SEGW?

Comment: Exactly, you need define your entityset